# Is there a Perl module or technique that makes using long namespaces easier?

Tags: perl, namespaces

Some namespaces are long and annoying.  Lets say that i downloaded hypothetical package called FooFoo-BarBar-BazBaz.tar.gz, and it has the following modules:

```
FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill
FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bob
FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Ben
FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bozo
FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Brown
FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Berkly
FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Berkly::First
FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Berkly::Second
```

Is there a module or technique I can use that's similar to the C++ 'using' statement, i.e., is there a way I can do

```
using FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz;
```

which would then let me do

```
my $obj = Brown->new();

ok $obj->isa('FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Brown') ;  # true
# or...
ok $obj->isa('Brown'); # also true
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a name that is ""too long", and how you are using it in code such that its length becomes annoying?  Most code usually doesn't need to use explicit package or class names explicitly except in a very few places.

Comment: @Ether - There is a design thought that you should almost never export/import things from a module's namespace. The rationale is that by looking at code it's almost impossible to figure out which module a particular identifier was exported from, and that's valuable info readabaility-wise if there are a lot of modules used. This design consideration of course only applies to class-level stuff (not object methods) - in modules that are more object oriented and have less static identifiers, your point (most places don't need full module name) is spectacularly true.

Comment: Even in C++, there's  `use namespace std`, and std is only 3 characters!  So "too long" is really subjective.  :)  The main concern here for me is when using objects.  Object will never export subroutines, but the namespace associated with it may be long.  Something like `MyCompany::MyApp::Object::Instance` might not seem too bad, until you have to make a dozen of them, each from a different namespace!

Comment: “Object will never export subroutines”?  What does *that* mean?  As for long names, dative notation can make for more readable code.

Comment: By "Object will never export subroutines" I mean "These packages contain only subroutines that should only be called using method invocation.  These subroutines are not exported, nor make any sense when called using functional syntax."  I am assuming for the moment that the namespace has already been chosen, so other naming conventions wouldn't help here.  (I am curious as to what you mean by dative notation, though; do you have an example?)

Comment: @DVK: that rule only really holds for `@EXPORT` symbols, not `@EXPORT_OK` -- if one says `use Foo::Bar 'blah';`, then it is easy to see that any use of blah() in the code came from Foo::Bar.

Comment: @Robert: It is hard to format it so that it looks good here, but something like `my $col_part = new Unicode::Collate:: \n\t normalization => undef, \n\t level => 1, \n\t;` is along the lines I mean.  Dative syntax is often referred to as “indirect object” syntax, albeit somewhat inaccurately insofar as dative syntax is actually orthogonal to indirect objects in the Perl sense.

Comment: @Ether - not quite, you still need to go all the way up to the "`use`" statement to find out though it's definitely a lot better than `EXPORT`ed ones. For large codebases, it's still a lot harder than explicitly prefixing with the package name.

Comment: @DVK: come on, how hard is it to search for `blah` in the file to answer the question "where did blah() come from?" -- the first occurrence of `blah` is in that `use` line. That's not hard at all.

Comment: @Ether - when you're trying to understand an unfamiliar blob of code during production emergency at 2am - HARD. And that's my criteria for separatng "easy to read" from "golf" :)

Comment: @tchrist thanks for the clarification.  I've never heard of it referred to in that way before, always as 'indirect object'.  Or seen it referred to that way in the any of Perl's docs. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [aliased](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?aliased) pragma does this:

```
use aliased 'FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill';

my $bill = Bill->new;
```

`aliased` is syntactic sugar for

```
use constant Bill => 'FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill';
# or 
sub Bill () {'FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill'}
```

The downside of this is that normal usage of package names as arguments is done with quoted strings:

```
$obj->isa('FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill')
```

But the constant subroutine needs to be a bare word:

```
$obj->isa(Bill);
```

Which just seems like a bug waiting to happen.

Alternatively, you could just use Perl's builtin support for namespace aliasing:

```
package Foo::Bar::Baz::Bill;

sub new {bless {}}

package Foo::Bar::Baz::Tom;

sub new {bless {}}

package main;

BEGIN {*FBB:: = *Foo::Bar::Baz::}  # the magic happens here

say FBB::Bill->new;  # Foo::Bar::Baz::Bill=HASH(0x80fd10)

say FBB::Tom->new;   # Foo::Bar::Baz::Tom=HASH(0xfd1080)
```

Regarding the `->isa('shortname')` requirement, the aliased stash method works with quoted strings as usual:

```
my $obj = FBB::Bill->new;

say $obj->isa('FBB::Bill');           # prints 1
say $obj->isa('Foo::Bar::Baz::Bill'); # prints 1
```

The effect of a compile time alias `BEGIN {*short:: = *long::package::name::}` is global across all packages and scopes.  This is fine as long as you pick an empty package to alias into.

Comment: Yay, I figured there'd be something like this.   Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  It looks like there is also `namespace::alias`, but it doesn't look quite as mature at the moment.

Comment: `namespace::alias` is an interesting idea, since its effect is lexically scoped.  However as of now, it only works on a narrow subset of perl versions and platforms due to its deep coupling with perl's C implementation.

Comment: Interesting note: if you use a constructor like `new { my $class = shift; return bless {}, $class } ` , then `$class` will be set to the alias.  However, AFTER the object is blessed, a `ref $class` returns the non-aliased namespace!

Answer (score 0):

If the module only needs to have class methods called on it then subclassing it is the simplest solution.  This can of course be done dynamically at runtime to select where Bill goes.

```
push @Bill::ISA, "FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill";
print Bill->isa("FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill");
1

sub FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill::yo {
  print "FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill here\n";
}

Bill->yo
FooFoo::BarBar::BazBaz::Bill here
```