# Require Perl Modules using an Aliased Name

Tags: perl

*****The following is background to help explain what I've tried so far. If you'd prefer to read the main question first, skip to the bottom.*****

---

#### Starting Out

My `Baz` module invokes a number of other modules, all similar, each of which is one level down in the namespace. The ones of interest here compose the `Thing` role. In addition to the individual `require` statements, the constant list `ALL_THINGS` enumerates the relevant `Thing` modules for use later on. My original code looks like so:

```perl
package Foo::Bar::Baz;

use constant ALL_THINGS => qw{ Foo::Bar::Baz::ThingA Foo::Bar::Baz::ThingB ... };

require Foo::Bar::Baz::ThingA;
require Foo::Bar::Baz::ThingB;
[...]
```

---

#### Eliminating Redundancy

As I mentioned, there are quite a lot of `Thing` modules, and I'm still adding more. Each time I create a new `Thing` class, I have to add a new `require` statement and also add the same identical text to the `ALL_THINGS` list. In order to avoid this duplication, I wanted to replace the individual `require` lines with a loop iterating over `ALL_THINGS`. I added this, which works fine by itself:

```perl
foreach my $module (ALL_THINGS) {
    eval "require $module";
}
```

However this solution doesn't seem to play well with my next change.

---

#### Improving Readability

The full module name for each `Thing` is long and unwieldy. I'd like to alias the package name to make it easier to type/read. I looked at `Package::Alias`, but it seems that will `use` them, which I'd like to avoid if possible. The best solution I've come to so far is the pattern suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035542/is-there-a-perl-module-or-technique-that-makes-using-long-namespaces-easier):

```perl
BEGIN { *Things:: = *Foo::Bar::Baz:: ; }
```

This also works, in the sense that it allows me to use `Thing::ThingA->classMethod`. However, unsurprisingly, it doesn't work in the `require` loop above, as `require Thing::ThingA` searches `@INC` for `Thing/ThingA.pm` rather than `Foo/Bar/Baz/ThingA.pm`.

---

## Main Question: Putting Them Together

I'd like to cut down the long package names (i.e. `Foo::Bar::Baz::ThingA`) in my `ALL_THINGS` list to `Things::ThingA`, but still be able to use that same list to build my `require` statements in a loop.

- Is there a different way to alias `Foo::Bar::Baz::` as `Things::` such that I can `require Things::ThingA`?
- Or, if I'm doing the alias part right, is there a way to dereference `Things::ThingA` to `Foo::Bar::Baz::ThingA` in (or before?) the eval so that `require` finds the correct package?
- Is there some other generally accepted method of tying together packages at different levels of the same namespace to obviate the need for all this?

**Bonus Questions (related to `eval "require $x"`):**

- In the [perldoc for constant](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html#CAVEATS) it says that constant *lists* are not actually read-only. Does that create a security concern with the use of `eval`?
- If so, is there a safer way to do it without the need to load additional modules?
- Being somewhat new to Perl, are there any more subtle differences I might have missed between this approach and my previous one (individual `require` statements for each module)?

---

**Note: I accepted Dave Sherohman's answer, as it most fully addresses the question I asked. However, I ultimately implemented a solution based on lordadmira's answer.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How black do you like your magic?

We all know that, in order to `require` modules, Perl looks through `@INC` to find the file it wants to load.  One of the little-known (and even-less-used) aspects of this process is that `@INC` isn't limited to only contain filesystem paths.  You can also put coderefs there, allowing you to hijack the module loading process and bend it to your will.

For the use case you've described, something like the following (untested) should do the trick:

```
BEGIN { unshift @INC, \&require_things }

sub require_things {
  my (undef, $filename) = @_;

  # Don't go into an infinite loop when you hit a non-Thing:: module!
  return unless $filename =~ /^Thing::/;

  $filename =~ s/^Thing::/Foo::Bar::Baz::/;
  require $filename;  
}
```

Basically what this does is, as the first entry in `@INC`, it looks at the name of the requested module and, if it starts with `Thing::`, it loads the corresponding `Foo::Bar::Baz::` module instead.  Simple and effective, but *really* easy to confuse future maintenance programmers (including yourself!) with, so use with caution.

---

As an alternate approach, you also have the option of specifying a package name in the module which doesn't correspond to the physical path of the file - the two are normally the same by convention, to make life easier when reading and maintaining the code, but there's no technical requirement for them to match.  If the file `./lib/Foo/Bar/Baz/Xyzzy.pm` contains

```
package Thing::Xyzzy;

sub frob { ... };
```

then you would use it by doing

```
require Foo::Bar::Baz::Xyzzy;
Thing::Xyzzy::frob();
```

and Perl will be perfectly happy with that (even though your coworkers may not be).

---

Finally, if you want to get rid of `ALL_THINGS`, take a look at [Module::Pluggable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Pluggable).  You give it a namespace, then it finds all available modules in that namespace and gives you a list of them.  It can also be set to `require` each module as it is found:

```
use Module::Pluggable require => 1, search_path => ['Foo::Bar::Baz'];
my @plugins = plugins;
```

`@plugins` now contains a list of all `Foo::Bar::Baz::*` modules, and those modules have already been loaded with `require`. Or you can just call `plugins` without assigning the result to a variable if you only care about loading the modules and don't need a list of them.

Comment: I like my magic like my coffee. As black as possible.

Lol, I actually noticed that note somewhere in the perldocs, but I thought hooking from @INC that way might be a bit beyond my skills. I'm thrilled to see an example implementation of it (and how simple it actually is), and I think that answer might justify this question all on its own.

Comment: I also happen to have Module::Pluggable available in our prepacked lib directory, so I will give that a look as well. Each `Thing` is pretty small, but loading them all unnecessarily might be expensive. I have a hash that holds lists - smaller subsets of `Things` to load and search for based on the type of system it's run on, so normally I'd want to only require what's in that list. But there is an "All" fallback option, hence the need for a list of all modules. It also makes it easier to write a test to check for typos in the sublists. Either way, Pluggable looks great.

Comment: @BryKKan - Even if you decide you don't want to auto-load all Things, you can just leave out the `require => 1` and get a complete list of them without loading any, which saves the hassle of manually maintaining a master list.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a different way to alias Foo::Bar::Baz:: as Things:: such that I can require Things::ThingA?

Yes. There are two requirements for this to work:

1. Create the package alias as you have already done.

   ```
   BEGIN { *Things:: = *Foo::Bar::Baz:: }
   ```
2. Create a symbolic link to `mylibs/Things` from your `mylibs/Foo/Bar/Baz` directory (where `mylibs` is the path to your Perl modules)

   (Make a link from the `Foo/Bar/Baz.pm` file to `Things.pm`, too, if you want)

Once you have done this, and call `eval "require Things::Quux"` or `eval "use Things::Quux"`, Perl will load the file in `mylibs/Things/Quux.pm`, which is the same as the `mylibs/Foo/Bar/Baz/Quux.pm` file. That file has a `package Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux` statement in it, but since that package is already aliased to the `Things::Quux` namespace, all of its subroutines and package variables will be accessible in either namespace.

> Is there some other generally accepted method of tying together packages at different levels of the same namespace to obviate the need for all this?

It's not clear what your object model is, but if `*::Thing1`, `*::Thing2`, etc. are all implementations of some common base class, you could consider a factory method in the base class.

```
package Foo::Bar::Baz;
sub newThing {
    my ($class, $implementation, @options) = @_;
    eval "use $class\::$implementation; 1"
        or die "No $implementation subclass yet";
    no strict 'refs';
    my $obj = "$class\::$implementation"->new(@options);
    return $obj;
}
```

Now `Foo::Bar::Baz::Thing7` (which may or may not be aliased to `Things::Thing7`) will only be loaded if it is needed, say, from a call like

```
my $obj7 = Foo::Bar::Baz->newThing("Thing7",foo => 42);
print ref($obj7);   # probably  Foo::Bar::Baz::Thing7
```

Comment: The classes actually represent very different things, and are implemented wildly differently. The `Thing` role guarantees certain attributes for all of them, but each class requires a different subset of those attributes to be provided as constructor arguments, deriving the others. As a workaround, each has a common class method `Thing->find_all` which finds all the things of that type on the system (using some unspecified - and varying - means), creates an object representing each, then returns a list of references to those objects.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it does offer a way to do it, and the discussion of a factory model is helpful. However, using links doesn't really address my question as posed. While it would technically work, it requires altering the environment in which the script runs rather than the script itself. It also makes step (1) redundant, as with the link you suggested, I could simply `require Thing::ThingA`, no package alias required.

Answer (score 2):

Messing with typeglobs is like nuclear overkill here.  Module::Runtime is the standard way to load modules at runtime based on configuration data.  At this point everything can be ordinary variables.  There is no benefit in using a constant here.

Here is my suggestion as from our IRC chat.

```
package Foo::Bar::Baz;

use strict;
use Module::Runtime "require_module";
use List::Util "uniq";

my $prefix = "Things::LetterThings";
my %prop_module_map = (
   foo => [ qw{ThingC ThingF ThingY} ],
   bar => [ qw{ThingL ThingB} ],
   baz => [ qw{ThingA ThingB ThingC ThingE ThingG ThingH ThingZ} ],
   # or
   # ALL => [ qw{ThingA .. ThingZ} ],
);
my @all_modules = uniq map { @$_ } values %prop_module_map;

sub load_modules {
  my $self = shift;

  # map module list if matching property found, otherwise use ALL_MODULES
  my $modules = $prop_module_map{$self->prop} ?
     $prop_module_map{$self->prop} :
     \@all_modules;

  #only do the map operation on the list we actually need to use
  my @modules = map { join "::", $prefix, $_  } @$modules;

  foreach my $module (@modules) {
    require_module($module);
  }
}

1;
__END__
```

Comment: This is indeed the solution I ultimately went with. Thank you for adding it here so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution based on an example in [perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables) that seems to work, though I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. I'm posting it with the hope that someone can improve upon it, or at least explain it/provide feedback.

```perl
foreach my $package (ALL_THINGS) {
    no strict "refs";
    $package = *{$package}{PACKAGE}."::".*{$package}{NAME};
    eval "require $package";
}
```

---

**Edit:** After following the link over to perlref, I found this blurb in section (7):

> ***foo{NAME}** and ***foo{PACKAGE}** are the exception, in that they return strings, rather than references. These return the package and name of the typeglob itself, rather than one that has been assigned to it. So, after ***foo=*Foo::bar**, ***foo** will become **"*Foo::bar"** when used as a string, but ***foo{PACKAGE}** and ***foo{NAME}** will continue to produce "main" and "foo", respectively.

From that, it makes sense that `*Things{PACKAGE}` will always resolve to `Foo::Bar::Baz`, since that's the package we're working in, and therefore the package that the typeglob "belongs to". In my code above, `$package` resolves to `Things::ThingA`, not `Things`, so we get `*Things::ThingA{PACKAGE}`. Similarly, the second part becomes `*Things::ThingA{NAME}`. I could hazard a few guesses as to why that might be working, but the truth is I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes please elaborate on this. So if `$package` is `Thing::ThingA`, the `*{$package}{PACKAGE}` will expand to `Foo::Bar::Baz` somehow? and `*{$package}{NAME}` will expand to `ThingA`? Also, why is this a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

NAME and PACKAGE are there mainly so that you can find out what package and name a reference came from.  Other than that is a way to return the variable name rather than the variable value for e.g. debugging.

```
printf "%s\n", __PACKAGE__; my $y = \*ydp; pp *$y{PACKAGE}, *$y{NAME};
W
("W", "ydp")
```